# How to mock DbSet<T>.Load() using Moq?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework, moq

I am trying to unit test the following lines of code:

```
myDbContext.myDbSet.Load()
myObservableCollection = myDbContext.myDbSet.Local
```

My testmethod looks like this:

```
Dim dataMyDbSet = New List(Of myDbSet) From {
        new myDbSet() With{.Id=1},
        new myDbSet() With{.Id=1},
        new myDbSet() With{.Id=1}
        }.AsQueryable()

Dim myDbSetMock = New Mock(Of DbSet(of myDbSet))
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable (Of myDbSet)).Setup(Function(m) m.Provider).Returns(dataMyDbSet.Provider)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable (Of myDbSet)).Setup(Function(m) m.Expression).Returns(dataMyDbSet.Expression)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable (Of myDbSet)).Setup(Function(m) m.ElementType).Returns(dataMyDbSet.ElementType)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable (Of myDbSet)).Setup(Function(m) m.GetEnumerator).Returns(dataMyDbSet.GetEnumerator)

myDbSetMock.Setup(Function(x) x.Local).Returns(New ObservableCollection(Of myDbSet)(dataMyDbSet))

Dim MyDbContextMock = New Mock(of dbCrashtestNcap)
MyDbContextMock.Setup(function (f) f.myDbSet).Returns(myDbSetMock.Object)

Dim crashService = New CrashService(MyDbContextMock.Object)
Dim result = crashService.GetOcNcapKlassen()

Assert.That(result.Count,[Is].EqualTo(3))
```

this gets me NullReferenceException on the first line with myDbContext.myDbSet.Load()

All my attempts to either mock Load() or to return a value for myDbContext.myDbSet (so that the `NullPointerException` does not exist) have failed

A (dirty) workaround that works is to change Load() in ToList() but I would prefer to keep Load() or at least understand if there is a solution. thanks in advance for your help. Solution could be either C# or vb.net that's not that important to me

Comment: `Load` or `ToList`, does it really matter? You shouldn't mock such methods.

Comment: @IvanStoev I don't have to mock ToList  that works fine without a Mock. But I have to mock Local, would that be an issue and if so, why?

Comment: I meant the extension method `Load`. It operates on `IQueryable` (same as `ToList`), so there is no need to mock it. You need to mock the `IQueryable` argument, but you already did that I guess.

Comment: Or may be that's the problem. You've mocked the generic `IQueryable (of T)`, but `Load` operates on non generic `IQueryable`, so probably you'd need to mock it similar to the generic one.

Comment: @IvanStoev, I only now found the time to check on that idea. That was exactly the issue. If you make that an answer, I'll make it the accepted one. Thanks for that hint!

Comment: You are welcome. But my comment was based on my general experience, while I'm dilettante in unit testing and VB.NET, so I'm pretty sure posting a self answer would be more appropriate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments by Ivan Stoev (thanks again!) my issue was that `Load()` does not operate on the generic version of IQueryable but the non-generic version. So to solve this problem I replaced my above four lines with the following ones and it works:

```
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable).Setup(Function(m) m.Provider).Returns(dataMyDbSet.Provider)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable).Setup(Function(m) m.Expression).Returns(dataMyDbSet.Expression)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable).Setup(Function(m) m.ElementType).Returns(dataMyDbSet.ElementType)
myDbSetMock.As(of IQueryable).Setup(Function(m) m.GetEnumerator).Returns(dataMyDbSet.GetEnumerator)
```

However if you want to make use of ToList() the generic version is required.

Answer (score 1):

You've already successfully set-up a mock for `Local`, which is a property on the `DbSet<T>` type, that you've also mocked. The `Load` method is a static method (I believe its even an extension method, but that doesn't matter for this case). Frameworks like Moq use proxy techniques to be bale to set mocks for different kind of objects. Although this is a nice solution, it prohibits you from mocking anything other than `virtual` or `abstract` types, so you cannot mock the static `Load` method out of the box using Moq.

What you could do is create a new method inside your unit, mark it `virtual`, and call the `Load` method in there:

```
   public class Unit
    {
        public void YourMethod()
        {
            // .. do stuff
            CallStaticMethod(/* maybe pass parameters? */);
            // .. do more stuff
        }

        public virtual void CallStaticMethod()
        {
            // call static method
            Console.WriteLine("This is a static method call!");
        }
    }

    public class UnitUnderTest : Unit
    {
        public override void CallStaticMethod()
        {
            // do whatever you want during testing only

            // possibly call base.CallStaticMethod() to execute base method.
        }
    }
```

Now in your unit test you need to use `UnitUnderTest` and modify that class to have it behave to your needs.

Comment: Thanks for that quick and complete answer. You're right, it is an extension method, at least that was the other Exception I had trouble with